# Need to add customized button in tinymce editor in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, tinymce

I am developing my projects with wordpress. Wordpress uses tinymce editor as we all know. I have used [Magazine Columns](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magazine-columns/)  pluing to display the content in different columns. This plugin adds the button to the editor in html mode but can't see those buttons in visual mode. My client cant see the html tags and he wants column tag to be added to visual mode. Can anyone suggest me how to display those buttons in visual mode or any idea on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i refuse to answer questions with such a low accept rating (you will have to work on this)

Answer (score 0):

Its a valuable way to organise to develop a projects in wordpress and it might allow everything to use in magazine columns to display the content in different columns. This plugin may adds the button to the editor in html mode..but, those buttons may visible in visual mode..  [Best Wordpress plugin](http://www.hdflvplayer.net/wordpress-video-gallery/hd-flv-player-features.php)